# Efficiently subtracting many columns

Tags: r

I need to perform the following example functions efficiently on a large data set:

```
df$A1-df$B1
df$A2-df$B2
df$A3-df$B3
```

Here are the sample data:

```
> df
  A1 A2 A3 B1 B2 B3
1  3  4  3  1  0  1
2  5  6  6  0  0  1
3  4  5  4  2  2  0
4  4  7  3  1  0  1
```

Is there a way I can tell R to subtract any column containing B from any column containing A, as long as their numbers are the same?

Thanks!

Comment: Just do `df[grep("A", names(df))] - df[grep("B", names(df))]`  (assuming that the order of columns for 'A' and 'B' are the same  or if you know the index `df[1:3] - df[4:6]`

Comment: If it is not in order, then order it `df1 <- df[gtools::mixedsort(names(df))]` and then do as above

Comment: Thanks akrun! That worked really well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can subset the columns 'A' and 'B' separately with `grep` and subtract them

```
df[grep("A", names(df))] - df[grep("B", names(df))]
```

or if the positions are known

```
df[1:3] - df[4:6]
```

---

In cases where the columns are not in order, then we order it first

```
df <- df[gtools::mixedsort(names(df))]
```

before doing the subtraction